# What is the difference between "чтобы" and "для того"?

Tags: грамматика

The dictionary says they both mean 'in order to'. Are they equivalent?

Answer (score 3):

Those are *not* equivalent elements.

**Чтобы** introduces the *purpose* of some action (described earlier or later) and can be used either on its own

> **Чтобы** метко в муху бить, нужно кока-колу пить.
>
> Надо бы закрыть окно - **чтобы** комары не залетели.

or (with more emphasis or formality) as the second part of the compound conjunction **(для того), чтобы**. Most often, **для того** can be omitted.

> **(Для того) чтобы** получить Нобелевскую, нужно сделать нечто
> выдающееся.

That compound conjunction can also be used in split form:

> **Для того** я тебе это говорю, **чтобы** ты хорошенько подумал.

In less typical cases **для того** can be used *without* **чтобы**:

> Сейчас сварю тебе борщ - **для того** я и пришла.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that you cannot use just "для того", you always need "чтобы" after that. But "чтобы" can be use in its own.

> Елена устроилась на работу (для того), чтобы заработать немного денег.

There is no difference whether you use "для того" or not. It can be omitted.